# Can you store the whole page instead of the state in Metro Winstore app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

The LayoutAwarePage helper has virtual methods to save/load a page state to reinstate it after navigated from another page.

I have only 2 pages and one of them has real state I want to maintain.

It seems really bug-prone approach to have it done correctly through save/load of the data (state) specifically.

I'd rather store the whole page and then push it somewhere it needs to be..

Unfortunately the Winstore apps use new paradigm which I am not familiar.

**Could anyone please help - what object can I save and where it has to be set to be shown correctly** (in silverlight I'd just cache UserControl object and then in App set it to the Root).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently it is done by using:

```
this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
```

in the constructor of the page which needs to be cached.